# How do I convert this string to an array with all the proper formatting?

Tags: python, arrays, string

At the moment it looks like this:

```
myString="['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']"
```

I want it to end up like this:

```
myArray=['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
```

How would I do this?

Comment: My first thought was it's a JSON array, but the quotes are swapped around. If they weren't: `import json; myArray=json.loads('["ASK","WHAT","etc"]')` is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> myString="['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']"
>>> list(map(lambda x:x.strip("'"), myString.strip('"[]').split(", ")))
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
```

or use this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(myString)
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
```